# suggest better parser to parse xml data getting from .net webserver

Tags: android

i need to get data along with images from .net web server.

i have large data around 250 images and 250 lines of data.

I am getting this data using xml webservices from the .net web server.

And parse it using android inbuilt xml parser.

But it takes more than 10 min of time.

I found that there is parser Libxml2 in iphone which is written in c language.

it parses the data while downloading from webserver.

but android inbuilt xml parser parses after completion downloading all the data from the web server.

from weeks of days i am struggling with this problem.

can any one please help me.

is there any better solution for my problem.

(Let me know add comment if any one don't understand my problem)

Comment: why do you have to wait for al the images to get downloaded before starting to parse the XML? Of the 10 minutes taken, how much time is spend downloading the iamges, and how much time is parsing really taking up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAX XML parser is available on Android and can read from any class that implements InputStream. Since URLConnection provides a way to return its underlying InputStream, it seems to me you could do something like the following...

```
URL xmlSource = new URL("some http path");
UrlConnection xmlConnection = xmlSource.openConnection();
org.xml.sax.InputSource xmlStream = new InputSource(xmlConnection.getInputStream());
```

I haven't tested this myself and Google is careful to warn that the included Sax implementation comes as-is, but it seems to me a good place to start. There are plenty of resources available online on using InputSource and implementing Sax callbacks.